# Get current date in xml view for field options in odoo 12?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

Want to evaluate the date format value with current using options attribute

```
<field name="last_date" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="options"> {
      "bg_color": "red: last_date <= datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')",
      "fg_color": "black"
    }</attribute>
</field>
```

Also I tired "& l e;" instead and both caused raised an error of none define entity

Any one knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the variable **current_date** instead of using it with another date. you will get the result.

**{ "bg_color": "red: last_date &lt=; current_date", "fg_color": "black" }**

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for quick response..

It assume ; is a separator between two options

lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: EntityRef: expecting ';', line 147, column 54

Comment: Can you suggest more where you have to add the color based on the condition? On the Tree view?

Comment: On the tree view you suppose to add for specified column with condition,then check   **<tree string="Something" decoration-danger="last_date &lt; current_date">**